# x:Bind image with null string

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

In XAML I have the following line:

```
<Image x:Name="MainImage" 
       Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.MainPic,Mode=OneWay,TargetNullValue={x:Null}}"
       Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
public string MainPic
{
    get
    {
        if (Data == null)
            return default(string);
        else
            return Data.Photos.ElementAtOrDefault(0).url;
    }
}
```

App compiles fine but during execution (since Data is populated after few seconds), the app crashes with the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.

Debugger breaks at:

```
            private void Update_ViewModel_MainPic(global::System.String obj, int phase)
            {
                if((phase & ((1 << 0) | NOT_PHASED | DATA_CHANGED)) != 0)
                {
 /*HERE>>*/          XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Image_Source(this.obj23, (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource) global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource), obj), null);
                }
            }
```

Apparently, this occurs since MainPic is returning null.

Now, this code works fine in WP8.1. I have tried returning uri which results in Compile time error. I believe only string can be binded to image source in Win 10 (?) I just want a blank white area until data is populated hence I don't wish to give a local image source as fallback. Can someone help me port this for Win 10?

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the users who answered, following conclusion is drawn (for UWP):

- If you're binding image source to a `string`, it cannot be `null` or
  empty `""`. A singe character `"x"` or a space `" "` would work.
- If you bind to a `BitmapImage`, returning `null` works.
- You can use any of the methods mentioned by @Justin-xl . For me,
  changing all vm's to stop returning null was hard. So adding a simple
  convertor to xaml also does the trick.

Here's the converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value as string, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>If you use `x:Bind`, the `Source` of the `Image` needs to bind to a property of the exact same type `ImageSource` (e.g. `BitmapImage`) instead of `string`, otherwise it will throw a compile-time error, which is exactly a compile-time binding is supposed to do. The old binding allows *strings* 'cause it uses *Reflection* to resolve the type for you during run-time.</s>

Turns out my explicit type theory was wrong (thanks to @igrali for pointing it out). The `Source` does take a `string` as long it's is not `null` or `''`. So it leaves us two options to fix this.

**Option 1**

Keep your `uri` as a `string`, but do a check in your `vm`, once it's `null` or `''`, return some dummy text (even returning an a letter `x` would work!).

**Option 2**

Change the `uri` from a *string* to a **BitmapImage**. Then you can use `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue` to handle nulls and invalid bindings.

```
... FallbackValue='http://Assets/SplashScreen.png' TargetNullValue='http://Assets/SplashScreen.png'}"
```

Comment: Even though in this particular case the null string is causing problems, technically, using {x:Bind } to bind to strings with valid image Uris will still work.

Comment: @igrali you know what, I just tested it n your right! Interesting though it needs to a **valid** url otherwise it will throw a compile-time error. I will update the answer.

Comment: @igrali, looks like it doesn't even need a valid uri, as long as it's not empty, it won't throw compile-time errors!

Comment: Thanks both options worked. I wonder why they have changed the default converter that kicks in when a string is binded. It does not seem to handle null or empty string. Hence even a single space " " works

Comment: Not exactly sure but it could be a bug in their conversion code?

Comment: Yes it looks like. I wonder why no-one has pointed out this. I have put a conclusion above along with a manual converter option to solve this issue. Changing code everywhere in vm was tedious for me since I use lot of null bindings.

Comment: Thanks @JustinXL, you saved my day!