# Showing images from the internet asynchronously

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my UWP application, I have a `ListView` with incremental loading. Now I need to also include an image in the `ListViewItem`. I tried directly giving it the URI.

where `ThumbnailImage` is just a string in my view model. The problem with this is that because of incremental loading, when I scroll down a little bit while the previous images are still loading, the app just hangs. Whereas if I let all the images appear and then scroll down, it works fine.

I've also tried the `ImageEx` control from the toolkit and it has the same problem.

I did some searching the only thing I found was `doing IsAsync = True` in XAML. But it seems that `IsAsync` is not available in UWP.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ...   
    public string ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My XAML `ListView` that gets filled incrementally

```
<ListView  Grid.Row="0"            
        SelectionMode="Single"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="SearchResultListView_ItemClick" >

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                            CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                            CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                            DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                            FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                            FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                            PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"
                            SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"
                            SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"
                            SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"
                            PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"
                            SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"
                            DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                            DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                            ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            CheckMode="Inline"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
            <UserControl >
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStatePhone">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ThumbnailImage.Width" Value="50"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ThumbnailImage.Height" Value="50"/>                                         
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateTablet">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers> 
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ThumbnailImage.Width" Value="70"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ThumbnailImage.Height" Value="70"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateDesktop">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1200" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ThumbnailImage.Width" Value="90"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ThumbnailImage.Height" Value="90"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="10"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ThumbnailImage}"                                              
                            Visibility="{x:Bind ThumbnailImage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityImage}}"
                            Name="ThumbnailImage"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" .../>                             

                    <Grid  Grid.Row="1"   
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Visibility="{x:Bind Source, Converter={StaticResource ConverterNameHere}}">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind lblSource, Mode=OneWay}" .../>

                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Source}" .../>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Visibility="{x:Bind Author, Converter={StaticResource ConverterNameHere}}">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind lblAuthor, Mode=OneWay}" .../>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Author}"  .../>
                    </Grid>

                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind EducationalLevel}" .../>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Row="4"
                                Grid.Column="1">

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind AccessRights}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Languages}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind TypeImages}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>                            

                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here's my incremental loading class:

```
public class ItemsToShow : ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private SearchResponse ResponseObject { get; set; } = new SearchResponse();  
    MyViewModel viewModel = null;


    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get
        {
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchResultDataStore.NextPageToken) && !SearchResultDataStore.IsFirstRequest) || SearchResultDataStore.StopIncrementalLoading)
                return false;

            if(SearchResultDataStore.IsFirstRequest)
            {
                using (var db = new DbContext())
                {
                    var json = db.UpdateResponse.First(r => r.LanguageId == DataStore.Language).JsonResponse;
                    Metadata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpdateApiResponse>(json).response.metadata.reply;
                }

                var returnObject = SearchResultDataStore.SearchResponse;
                ResponseObject = returnObject.response;

                //This will show a grid with some message for 3 seconds on a xaml page named SearchResultPage.
                Toast.ShowToast(ResponseObject.message, SearchResultPage.Current.ToastGrid);
            }
            else
            {
                SearchApiResponse returnObject = null;
                try
                {
                    returnObject = new SearchApiCall().CallSearchApiAsync(param1, param2, param3).Result;
                }
                catch
                {  
                    return false;
                }
                ResponseObject = returnObject.response;
            }

            try
            {
                return ResponseObject.documents.Count > 0;                                        
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
        {           
            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                foreach (var item in ResponseObject.documents)
                {             
                    this.Add(PrepareViewModel(item));
                }
            });  

            await Task.Delay(350);                
            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };

        }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }

    public MyViewModel PrepareViewModel(Document document)
    {
        viewModel = new MyViewModel();

        viewModel.property1 = document.value1;
        viewModel.property2 = document.value2;

        ...
        ...

        if(SearchResultDataStore.ShowImage)
        {            
            //thumbnailUrl is a string.
            viewModel.ThumbnailImage = document.thumbnailUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            viewModel.ThumbnailImage = "somegarbage.png";
        }

        ...
        ...

        return viewModel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Source should use BitmapImage.

Comment: I've tried that also, doesn't help, same results

Comment: UWP Community Toolkit has `ImageEx` control. You should Look into that

Comment: Have you tried using `x:Phase` and seeing if that makes any difference?

Comment: @AVK  I've mentioned in the question that I've already tried that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897154/xbind-image-with-null-string

Comment: @lindexi I've already handled the null and empty string conditions in my view model.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey That changes nothing.

Comment: How your *Thumbnail* property looks like? You may take a look at [Stephen Cleary's post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) regarding async properties, there is nice *NotifyTaskCompletion* class which you can probably use. Also you will need to rethink how to handle multiple downloads - design download manager (the simplest version may with some semaphores), so that you won't block yourself with parallel tasks. Using separate threads for downloads may be also a good idea. Nevertheless you have provided too little details in your question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a sample of this. The `Image` control shouldn't *hang* your app.

Comment: @JustinXL Well, if I just comment out the line <Image `Name="ThumbnailImage" .../>` from the XAML file, everything works just fine. I've added more code to my question.

Comment: Just of curiosity - you have property *ThumbnailImage*, a control with the name *ThumbnailImage* and you are binding to visibility also *ThumbnailImage* by using converter BoolToVisibility. IMHO it's not good naming choice.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you're using `x:Bind` for the source the binding is not updated automatically. 
To verify that's actually the root cause of your problem you could set a breakpoint in your value converter, and see how many time is called.

I'd suggest using `x:Bind ThumbnailImage, Mode=OneWay`

You might have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Make few steps:

1. Add `x:Phase` attribute to `Image` control. Set biggest than other value (for ex. all are "0", set "1" etc.)
2. Add `Mode=OneWay` to `Image` because your should know when property will be changed.
3. Add control extension to `Image` control with dependency property `ImagePath`. When property will be changed -> start to load image from net asynchronically (for ex. by `HttpClient`). When request will be finished -> get content and put it to `BitmapSource` and put it to the `Source` property of `Image`.

Be sure that original image's size not much more than `Image` control's size, because if it's true -> UI will be hang.